# Android drawables size conflict

Tags: android, android-layout

Noob question:

I'm designing an app that I need to run on both tablets and phones
and I came across this problem:

The size of tablet that I'm targeting is mdpi(1024x600) so I put all my images to mdpi folder.
When I ran it in my emulator -- which is also 1024x600 it works just fine.

But when I ran it on a phone all the images and texts are so big that they occupy the whole screen. I know the solution is to produce the same images of smaller variant and put it in lower dpi folder. However, the next lower dpi is 'ldpi'; I don't think there's a phone out there that is on that size and most of them are hdpi -- which is higher than my target tablet resolution, and it would only make my images much bigger on phones' screen. how do I handle this case?

Another Question:
If a tablet is hdpi and a phone is also hdpi but obviously they are different in screen size; how do you design your images specifically on each of them, considering they have the same drawable folder?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not to use the images as is but set their sizes in DP and a different layout for every screen size.